# How to tell when to evaluate limits directly without first evaluating left hand and right hand limits to prove limit existence

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Good day,
Are there any characteristics of functions such that I can tell on sight which functions have existing limits, and tell them apart from the functions which need further evaluation of left and right hand limits to prove existence of the limit? Then I could save time doing homework or in an exam.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As starting point, consider : $f(x) = [x : x\geq 0]$ and $[-x: x < 0]$.  Intuitively, the slope in the first quadrant is +1, and the slope in the 2nd quadrant is -1.  Therefore, the function can not be differentiable at $x=0$, because no matter how arbitrarily small you specify a *neighborhood* around $x=0$, there will be one value of $x$ in this neighborhood such that $f'(x) = -1,$ and one value of $x$ in this neighborhood such that $f'(x) = 1.$

Comment: Extending previous comment, consider the graph of $f'(x)$, which has a *discontinuity* at $x=0$.  As I understand the definition of limits, there is a direct association between this definition and the notion of *continuity*.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "differentiate" as in tell apart from something, not the calculus function. The sentence has been edited as of now.

Comment: Yes, I got that.  My point was that re my 1st comment, although the analysis is clear that the derivative can't exist at $x=0$, that might **not** be immediately obvious.  In the 2nd comment, when you *observe* that $f'(x)$ has a *discontinuity* at $x=0$, it becomes more obvious.  The idea is (assuming that you reduce the question to one involving *continuity*), sometimes continuity (or its lack) is not immediately obvious.